# Regular expression matching with string

Tags: regex, grep

I need a regular expression which match only string "MachineABC" and "MachineABCTest".

I tried expression like this : MachineABC["Test"]*. But its not working as expected. What is the right regular expression for this scenario.?

I was testing with the grep utility. eg : echo "MachineABCTest" | grep 'MachineABC["Test"]+'.
example grep returns null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That regex would be:

```
^MachineABC(Test)?$
```

If you want to make any part optional just group it with `?` notifier to make it optional (1 or 0 matches).

**Testing with egrep:**

```
echo "MachineABCTest" | egrep '^MachineABC(Test)?$'
MachineABCTest

echo "MachineABC" | egrep '^MachineABC(Test)?$'
MachineABC
```

Comment: Yes `^` is line start and `$` is line end anchor.

Comment: Can you please explain why removing '$' from the end cause the expression matches "MachineABCest" ? "?" is operator responsible for the optional part right?

Comment: In which example do you want to remove `$` (example 1 or 2?)

Comment: First example i changed to this - echo "MachineABCest" | egrep '^MachineABC(Test)?'

Comment: `(Test)?` this means `0` or `1` hit of `Test`, so removing `$` will make any  ting work after `MachineABC`

Comment: egrep matches the line and prints it when match is found. A better example of use of `$` would be: `echo "MachineABC123" | egrep -o '^MachineABC(Test)?$'` that fails to match but in absence of `$` here `echo "MachineABC123" | egrep -o '^MachineABC(Test)?'` will make match successful.